# It will take a while until/before the change takes an effect

Tags: sentence, conjunctions

Which is correct or sounds better to you?

It will take a while until the change takes an effect.
It will take a while before the change takes an effect.

Thank you

Comment: I think more natural would be *It will **be** a while before the change **takes effect**.*

Comment: The sentence suggested by @FumbleFingers is like a set phrase and is well-worn with extensive use.

Comment: @Kris: Not sure it's exactly "well-worn". The closest I could find in written form is [some time has to elapse before the change takes effect](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VTBHAAAAMAAJ&q=%22elapse+before+the+change+takes+effect%22&dq=%22elapse+before+the+change+takes+effect%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fJBTT5POJ-WR0AWWtsmOBg&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA), and it took a while to find even that. I did find one instance of ["some time before the change takes effect"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22some+time+before+the+change+takes+effect%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but it's not in the same context.

Comment: ...and there are *no* relevant instances of **until** *the change takes effect* in Google Books

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are valid, but have slightly differing connotations. "Before" seems to stress the span of time preceding the effect; "Until" seems to stress the change that will be effected after that span of time.

Additionally, I agree with FumbleFingers that the phrasing is awkward. His phrasing is a good alternative. Else you can rephrase it "It will take a while **for** the change **to be effected**." This eliminates the need to choose between your alternatives, but makes use of passive voice, which is of contested validity. Personally, I have never had a problem with its usage, but that is something you must decide for yourself, based on personal preference and the context for which you are writing.