# Should I use until or before in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, american-english, vocabulary, context, learning

- Don't hire that guy *before* you check his references.
- Don't hire that guy *until* you check his references.

Comment: Using *before* says that hiring depends on the references. *Until* says check and hire in that order, but not dependent as we'd expect.

Comment: Have you tried a dictionary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [It will take a while until/before the change takes an effect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59857/it-will-take-a-while-until-before-the-change-takes-an-effect) // I'd use 'Don't hire that guy before you have checked his references.'

Comment: If the the person has a criminal background, either should do fine.

Answer (score -1):

To me, they have the same meaning. They specify a time order and imply a dependency.